# Meaning of A and B in Wireshark Conversation View

Tags: wireshark

In Wireshark's conversation view, do A and B map to source and destination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the packets captured.  For example, if the first packet it sees is from 1.2.3.4 to 5.6.7.8, then 1.2.3.4 becomes endpoint A, and 5.6.7.8 is B.

But if the first packet captured is 5.6.7.8 to 1.2.3.4, then it's the reverse.

Comment: So A is the machine that started the conversation?

Comment: Not necessarily.  It depends when your capture starts.  You might start the capture in the middle of a conversation.

Comment: A is always the sender of that specific packet - not necessarily the source for the entire stream (the individual packet could just be part of a handshake response, for example). B is always the recipient of that specific packet - not necessarily the destination for the entire stream (the individual packet could just be part of a handshake response, for example).